# REGEX Match everything but / which starts with :

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i am writing a regular expression which should do the following:

Match everything which is not a /
Dont match if matched segment starts with :

Example:

**asdjhas**/**fdjkl**/**sdfds:dsfsdf**/:sdff/**sdffff**

The bolded parts should match with the regex. As you can see, all forward slashes are not matched as well as the part which starts with a : only.

I have come up with this: ([^/]+) which works as intended except it will also match parts that start with :. I tried using negative lookahead assertions but to be honest, i really do not understand them.

I am also using PHPs preg library to do the matching for me.

Thanks

Comment: Your instructions suggests it should match the `*fdjkl*` portion in your example but you didn't highlighted it, why? (You do not want it to be matched, or you omitted by accident?)

Comment: So you don't want a match if characters are between / ?

Comment: @pozs I think that he tried to highlight it but he couldn't get markdown to work quite the way he wanted

Comment: @pozs, Explosion Pills is correct, that part was meant to be bolded, basically only the fourth section ":sdff" should not be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you need, and it does work with your test string:

```
preg_match_all('@
   (?:    # start group
     ^    # start of string
     |    # OR
     /    # slash character
    )     # end grouping
    (     # start capture
    [^:/] # character class of anything except colon and slash
    .*?   # anything until...
    )     # end capture
    (?=   # start lookahead
    /     # literal slash (lookahead is used so it is not consumed
          # which allows a slash to be used to start the next group)
    |     # OR
    $     # end of the string
    )     # end lookahead
    @x', $str, $matches);
```

Edit: using lookbehind `(?<=` instead of `(?:` seems to work just fine too.

Comment: Lookbehind for the beginning `(?<=^|/)` and `[^/]*` instead of `.*?` could make it even better (+1 though)

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on

```
/(?::[^/]+/*)?
```

i.e.

```
$string = 'asdjhas/*fdjkl*/sdfds:dsfsdf/:sdff/sdffff';

$parts = preg_split('#/(?::[^/]+/*)?#', $string);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => asdjhas
    [1] => *fdjkl*
    [2] => sdfds:dsfsdf
    [3] => sdffff
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is just to use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead:

```
$string = 'asdjhas/fdjkl/sdfds:dsfsdf/:sdff/sdffff';
$m = preg_split('/\/(:[^\/]*\/?)?/', $string);
print_r(array_filter($m));
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdjhas
    [1] => fdjkl
    [2] => sdfds:dsfsdf
    [3] => sdffff
)
```

Comment: @Tomalak but according to his bolded characters it is not wrong ?

Comment: @Tomalak Of course I tried it, well we'll know if it's "correct" when the OP takes a look at our codes ...

Comment: @Tomalak I took a look by clicking on the edit button, and I saw the "intended" bolded characters, thanks for pointing my error out :)

Comment: That's better, but still not entirely correct. It fails for `'asdjhas/fdjkl/sdfds:dsfsdf/:sdff/sdffff/:asd'` ;-)